# Spring web flow: the flow XMLs are not being registered

Tags: java, spring-webflow

I am using spring webflow and I have registered all the flow xmls in the webflow.xml like this

```
 <!-- The Flow handler adapter, to handle flows request recieved by the dispatcher servlet -->
 <bean id="flowController" class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter">  
     <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor"/>  
 </bean>
<flow:flow-registry id="myflowRegistry" flow-builder-services="flowBuilderServices" >
        <!-- all xml files in base path and subfolders  -->    
        <flow:flow-location path="/WEB-INF/flows/payslips.xml" />          
        <flow:flow-location path="/WEB-INF/flows/admissions.xml" />
        <flow:flow-location id="cash-advance" path="/WEB-INF/flows/cashadvance.xml"/>
        <flow:flow-location path="/WEB-INF/flows/services.xml" />
        <flow:flow-location path="/WEB-INF/flows/undergradadm.xml" />
     </flow:flow-registry>   
  <bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping">
    <property name="order" value="0" />
    <property name="flowRegistry" ref="myflowRegistry" />

</bean>
```

Now when I tr to access any of these pages with payslips.go or cash-advance.go they dont work and give me :

```
Error 500: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
```

I am very new to webflow and It seems logical that it should work. The views in the spring MVC that are not part of the webflow or dont have any xmls defined under flow work perfectly fine because it has nothing to do with webflow. but these pages which have a flow defined. I dont think mozilla has anything to do with it.

On some other machine, these are working fine. there must be something with my own setup that its not letting it work.

May be this will help as well

```
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1060)
    at org.springframework.webflow.context.servlet.DefaultFlowUrlHandler.getFlowId(DefaultFlowUrlHandler.java:83)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(FlowHandlerMapping.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:184)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1057)
```

Thanks

Comment: Sorry for bumping this thread again but this issue is still open: I debugged a little and it seems that in <view-state> the view="payslips" (which is registered in payslips.properties) is not getting picked up. It comes as if it is " ",: an empty string. I even tried giving the jsp name and with and without full path to JSP like : /WEB_INF/payslips/paylisps.jsp but it still doesnt pick up. I am still stuck over this issue:

Comment: I added the webflow libs from spring into the ear/lib and it started working. I dont know how but on test and dev they are working without being added to the classpath of the server orbeing in the ear/lib. Or may be I am not aware of it.

Comment: You definitely need the WebFlow jars in your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I am configuring SWF:

```
<!--
    ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                                    SPRING WEB FLOW'S CONFIGURATION
    ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
-->

<!-- Creates a flow executor in Spring, responsible for creating and executing flows -->
<flow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor" flow-registry="flowRegistry" />

<!-- Load flow definitions and make them available to the flow executor -->
<flow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry">
    <flow:flow-location id="process-flow" path="/process/flows/process-flow.xml" />
</flow:flow-registry>

<!-- The FlowHandlerMapping helps DispatcherServlet to knowing that it should send flow requests to Spring Web Flow -->
<bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping">
    <property name="flowRegistry" ref="flowRegistry" />
</bean>

<!-- The FlowHandlerAdapter is equivalent to a Spring MVC controller in that it handles requests coming in for a flow and processes those requests -->
<bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor" />
</bean>
```

My flow is in the root of my web folder, but you can also use the WEB-INF dir; this way, the path should be "/WEB-INF/foo/bar.xml/".

I hope it helps, regards.